# Perl Tk update(redraw) widgets in sub(in thread)

Tags: multithreading, perl, tk-toolkit

I have some widgets, checkboxes actually. And I have variables that contains their value. I have shared this variables and called a sub with creating new thread.
Variables change into this sub but look of widgets stays unchanged. So that is the question: how colud I redraw widgets or update their look somehow... or how could I rebuild my programm so they will update automatically or something.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using threads and Tk is not easy. See [Perl Tk and Threads](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=732294) on PerlMonks for tips and tricks.

Do you really need threads? Using `Tk::after` or `$widget->update` you can usually update widgets to changing values.

Comment: I think I realy need thread because I need to have an opportunity to stop function in main program